Serre's elliptic curve example for integral $j$
I am reading Serre's 1972 paper. I am trying to understand his examples in the case where $j$ is integral. In section 5.9, he gives the following example:

$y^2=x^3-2x^2-x$. $v_2(\Delta)$ implies $\Phi_2 \cong \mathrm{SL}(2,3)$. The image of $\Phi_2$ in $\text{Aut}E[\ell]$, $\ell \ge 3$ is a group of order 24 that acts irreducibly; moreover the group is not abelian and does not contain any abelian subgroups of index 2. We deduce $\rho_{\ell}(G)$ cannot be contained in a Borel subgroup or the normaliser of a Cartan subgroup; further since it contains either a Cartan subgroupu or a semi-Cartan subgroup (coming from the inertia at $\ell$) Proposition 17 shows that $\rho_{\ell}(G)=\mathrm{Aut}E[\ell]$ for all $\ell \ge 3$. For $\ell=5$, we must moreover check that $\rho_{\ell}(G)$ contains an element $s$ such that $\text{Tr}(s)^2/\text{det}(s)=3$...

I do not understand why we know that $\Phi_2$ must act irreducibly? And this is most likely basic group theory but I do not understand why the image cannot be contained the Borel or normaliser of a Cartan? Why must it contain a Cartan? Lastly, I don't see why $\ell=5$ requires additional work?

By Néron-Ogg-Shafarevich (see the paper Good reduction of abelian varieties by Serre-Tate), $\Phi_2$ acts faithfully on every $E[\ell]$ with $\ell \geq 3$, and $\Phi_2 \cong SL(2,3)$ as is written.
If $SL(2,3)$ was contained in a Borel $B$, then its derived subgroup would be contained in $B’=\begin{pmatrix}1 & \ast\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, so $\Phi_2’$ would be trivial or cyclic of order $\ell$. But you can check that $|\Phi_2’|$ has cardinality $8$ and isn’t abelian, so that’s impossible.
If $\Phi_2$ acted reducibly, its image would be contained (up to conjugacy) in $B$, which we just disproved.
If $\Phi_2$ is contained in the normalizer $N$ of a Cartan subgroup $C$, consider the map $\Phi_2 \rightarrow N \rightarrow N/C$. Then its kernel is contained in $C$, hence is abelian. So $\Phi_2$ has an abelian subgroup of index at most two, which you can check does not happen.
Read the previous sections of the paper (I think part one, you can skim until you find something relevant) to see what the image of $I_{\ell}$ in $\mathrm{Aut}(E[\ell])$ is (usually quite large). Then, as Serre says, just apply Proposition 17.
$\ell=5$ requires additional work because Proposition 17 doesn’t quite apply in this case. You will need to apply 2.6 more carefully.

Thank you so much! I had a clarification to make - what does it mean for $\Phi_2$ to act irreducibly? and where exactly is this fact used?

I’m not sure if it’s used, since here, it’s equivalent to being contained in the Borel. “Acts irreducibly” means exactly “its action on [whatever] is irreducible”,

Makes sense, thank you so much!

I also think there might be a slight typo. The derived subgroup of $SL(2,3)$ has order 8 (as it is $Q_8$) and not 12. The argument still holds though. Am I correct?

Oops, my mistake. It really doesn’t change anything, I think.
